# Key colours JFreeCharts

Tags: colors, charts, jfreechart, pie-chart, stacked-chart

I'm generating stackedbarcharts and piecharts using jfreecharts. Both types of charts use the same labels. For example I have John, Mike, Sandra, Pushpalika in both. Is there a way I can ensure that the colour used to represent each person is the same across both types of charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if the series keys in your CategoryDataset (for the bar chart) are in the same order as the keys in your PieDataset (for the pie chart), the auto-selected colors will be the same on both charts.  However, if you really want to be sure then you should set the colors manually, using PiePlot's [setSectionPaint()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot.html#setSectionPaint%28int,%20java.awt.Paint%29) method and the stacked bar renderer's [setSeriesPaint()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setSeriesPaint%28int,%20java.awt.Paint%29) method.